# Set two MX records for a domain and a subdomain

Tags: email-server, mx-record

Let's suppose I have a domain named `example.com`. I'm using `sendgrid` to only send/track emails and `zoho` as a mail server.

I already have these records and Everything works fine:

```
example.com     1799    IN  MX  10 mx.zoho.com.
example.com     1799    IN  MX  20 mx.zoho.com.
example.com     3599    IN  TXT "v=spf1 a include:sendgrid.net include:zoho.com ~all"
zohomail._domainkey.example.com. 1799 IN TXT    "v=DKIM1\; k=rsa\; p=......."
```

Now I want to whitelabel my domain to get rid of the “via sendgrid.net” message. They want me to add another `MX` record but for the subdomain:

```
MX  delivery.example.com mx.sendgrid.net.
TXT m1._domainkey.example.com k=rsa; t=s; p=...
TXT delivery.example.com v=spf1 include:sendgrid.net ~all
```

I know that you shouldn't use different `MX` servers for the same domain, but how about subdomain (same question for `SPF` and `DKIM` records)

Edit:

I'm also worried if what I'm doing is considered as spam, for further info `A` and `CNAME` records  are set like this:

```
example.com.        1799    IN  A   my_IPV4

CNAME *.example.com is an ilias of example.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problems with adding SPF and DKIM entries for subdomain. If all your mails to trough Sendgrid will come from user@delivery.example.com, that's ok, because SFP and DKIM entries would be applied only for subdomain, not for main domain example.com. For example `udemy.com` use different SPF entries for udemy.com and email.udemy.com.

Comment: thanks, I think I should remove `CNAME *.example.com as an alias fo example.com`  correct me if I'm wrong. I also have on last question, do I need to create `no-reply@delivery.example.com` email even though it's only used for outgoing mails?

Comment: @Raftel I think you don't need e-mail `no-reply@delivery.example.com`, it's no-reply, and all your MX for delivery.example.com will point on Sendgrid. Also about CNAME, you should configure it to sendgrid, at it mentioned in documentation: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Glossary/cname.html